# Problem when trying to install Libreoffice 3.5.1 due to lock file

Tags: libreoffice

I tried to install Libreoffice 3.5 from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa), but this problem appears:

```
ERROR: unopkg cannot be started. The lock file indicates it as already running. If this does not apply, delete the lock file at:
/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/.lock
dpkg : erreur de traitement de /var/cache/apt/archives/python-uno_1%3a3.5.1-1ubuntu1~oneiric1_i386.deb (--unpack) :
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Treatment of deferred stock (« triggers ») for « libreoffice-common »...
Errors were encountered while processing :
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-uno_1%3a3.5.1-1ubuntu1~oneiric1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Hi, could you please edit your question add the full error message you get? Also, what is the PPA you're using to get LibreOffice?

Comment: done,waiting for your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug, as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/960867).

According to that report, you should delete the lock file then proceed with install. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/.lock
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And packages should be fixed.

Comment: @khaled great! If my answer led you to the solution, please mark my answer as the right one. Cheers!